# Your card was declined stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am getting below error while sign-up in the project in local for stripe payment.

> Your card was declined. Your request was in live mode, but used a known test card.

I don't have any idea why it comes.

Can anyone help me to come out of it?

Comment: @Jordan i am trying to singup in local. can you tell me how can i change live mode to test mode

Comment: Are you using the Stripe API to make this request? If so, make sure you use the API test secret and publishable keys and not the live ones.

Answer (score 25):

**2023 update:**

1. Visit [Stripe Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/) and then click on [API](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/apikeys) on side menu.

[image: Side menu on the stripe dashboard]

2. Ensure the test mode is toggled

   [image: Tabs on the stripe dashboard]
3. Now copy the `Publishable key` and the `Secret key`

**NOTE:** The test values starts with `pk_test_*` and `sk_test_*`

---

**Old Answer:**

You need to use the API keys for test mode

Visit [Stripe Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/) and then click on [API](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys) on side menu.

[image]

Now copy the values from

```
Test Secret Key
Test Publishable Key
```

See the marked values

[image]

Answer (score 11):

**2019 Update:** You now have to toggle "Viewing Test Data" and then use that Publishable Key. They're different!

Answer (score 5):

You are probably using the live mode in stripe. On your stripe dashboard (on the website), there is a toggle button for the development/live mode. Make that into development or test mode, you shouldn't get the error anymore